# Special characters with Ruby XML Builder

Tags: xml, ruby, builder

I'm trying to a Google kml tour with ruby and I get a syntax error with this code

```
xml = builder.gx:Tour
```

It doesn't like the colon.  Is there a way to force it to compile this?

Answer (score 9):

Had to do

```
xml.tag!("gx:tour")
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and if you want to put some value, it would be something like

```
xml.tag!("gx:tour", "value of gx:tour", "attribute1"=>"attribute1val", "attribute2"=>"attribute2val", ..., "attributeN"=>"attributeNval")
```

Answer (score 4):

If You want to add another tag inside the tag then

```
xml.tag!("tag:name", attribute: "value") do |t|
   t.title("value for title")
end
```

And if you want to put a simple value then

```
xml.tag!("tag:name","value for tag", attribute: "attribute value")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2 of Builder there is [some support for namespacing](http://builder.rubyforge.org/).

So now if you want to achieve the same result you can add a space before the colon:

```
xml = builder.gx :Tour
```

Answer (score 0):

Super old question but in Rails 5.1.5 with Builder 3.2.3 it is very simple to use namespaces, nesting, etc. The following is a contrived example but I think it shows all the different combinations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root simple="foo" xmlns:example="http://www.example.com/example.dtd">
  <container>
    <element>A normal element</element>
    <example:namespaced_element>An element in the "example" namespace</example:namespaced_element>
  </container>
  <example:namespaced_container>
    <element_with_attribute attribute="foo">Another element</element_with_attribute>
    <example:namespaced_element_with_attribute attribute="bar">Another namespaced element</example:namespaced_element_with_attribute>
  </example:namespaced_container>
  <container_with_attribute attribute="baz">
    <empty_element/>
    <example:namespaced_empty_element/>
  </container_with_attribute>
  <example:namespaced_container_with_attribute attribute="qux">
    <empty_element_with_attribute attribute="quux"/>
    <example:namespaced_empty_element_with_attribute attribute="corge"/>
  </example:namespaced_container_with_attribute>
</root>
```

And this is the builder template to produce the above:

```
#encoding: UTF-8
xml.instruct! :xml, version: '1.0'
xml.root simple: 'foo', 'xmlns:example': 'http://www.example.com/example.dtd' do
  xml.container do
    xml.element 'A normal element'
    xml.example :namespaced_element, 'An element in the "example" namespace'
  end
  xml.example :namespaced_container do
    xml.element_with_attribute 'Another element', attribute: 'foo'
    xml.example :namespaced_element_with_attribute, 'Another namespaced element', attribute: 'bar'
  end
  xml.container_with_attribute attribute: 'baz' do
    xml.empty_element
    xml.example :namespaced_empty_element
  end
  xml.example :namespaced_container_with_attribute, attribute: 'qux' do
    xml.empty_element_with_attribute attribute: 'quux'
    xml.example :namespaced_empty_element_with_attribute, attribute: 'corge'
  end
end
```